# why that button doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

- when i press Generic button it shows stack panel with group of buttons
- when i press any of those buttons.it should show a user control in the large space
- my trouble that when i press any button in stack panel it doesn't show user control in space
  [image]

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {

      GenericName use1 = new GenericName();

      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void btn_Generic(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        stackPanel1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }

      private void btn_GeneralInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
       Container.Child = use1;
      } 

    }


  }
  ```

Comment: Can we see the Xaml code for one of the stackpanel buttons

Comment: And wht type of element is `Container`, your xaml will help diagnose the problem

Comment: @ sa_ddam213 .. thanks alot for your interest to answer my question .. actually i forgot to add click event handler for buttons in xaml code ....i would like to have a personal contact with u by emails ..ofcourse if u don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the five buttons dont have OnClick set as btn_Generic i.e.

```
<asp:Button ID="1" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Generic" />
```

Comment: though it was a silly mistake ..but i stayed more than hour thinking about it ..thank you